# How to perform functionality for dynamically created button in onTouch

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have set Image from gallery in `RelativeLayout` and trying to place `Button` dynamically with separate id, during `onTouch`. Now I am trying to set and get values depending upon the button id. (In my code, now am getting same value for all `Button`).

My Code:

```
viewGroup= (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(createdPinViewGroup);
viewGroup.setId(R.id.ImageId);
i =0
selectedPicture.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 int x = (int) event.getX();
 int y = (int) event.getY();
 rparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 rparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ACCESSIBILITY_LIVE_REGION_ASSERTIVE);
 rparams.leftMargin = x;
 rparams.topMargin = y;
 rparams.height = 48;
 rparams.width = 60;
 btn = new Button(getBaseContext());
 btn.setId(i + 1);
 btn.setText("B" + i);
 btn.setLayoutParams(rparams);
 viewGroup.addView(btn);
 i++;

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Button is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
});
```

Comment: What is "i"?, Why u used? This adds multiple button in your view

Comment: you are doing i+1 so value of i is not changing. change i+1 to i++. My bad you are doing i++ at the last..

Comment: @AnandMakwana "i" for set button id.

Comment: where is the code for  setonclick listener for the button ?. it should be inside the scope of the button.

Comment: post thefull code please

Comment: @manDroid added code for setOnclick listener

Comment: @KarthikaPB please view my code updation.

Comment: ni your code what do you meant by (In my code, now am getting same value for all Button). ?

Comment: @KarthikaPB I need setting the value based on the id. Now am getting previously  set value in created all button.

Comment: were do you try that it's not seen inside onclick?

Comment: Still am searching for solution

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id inside the onclick itself try this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Button is Clicked "+v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

});

Comment: Yes am getting id but i have to set the value depend upon the id. This is the question.

After that based on the id, retrieve the value

Comment: what value do younwanna get text of the clicked button?or anything else.be clear with your question

Comment: I got result. Now am saving the details in Hashmap and retrieved from the Hash map. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try these it may work for you:

```
 Button[] btn = new Button[100];

 viewGroup= (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(createdPinViewGroup);
 viewGroup.setId(R.id.ImageId);
 i =0
 selectedPicture.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 int x = (int) event.getX();
 int y = (int) event.getY();
 rparams = new   
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 rparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ACCESSIBILITY_LIVE_REGION_ASSERTIVE);
 rparams.leftMargin = x;
 rparams.topMargin = y;
 rparams.height = 48;
 rparams.width = 60;
 i++;
 btn[i] = new Button(getBaseContext());
 btn[i].setId(i + 1);
 btn[i].setText("B" + i);
 btn[i].setLayoutParams(rparams);
 viewGroup.addView(btn);

 btn[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your desired functionality 
         } 
      }); 
    }
```

Comment: Okay Thanks. Each button creation, i have to set with different values. So am using Hash Map to save. On button click retrieving the value, which value i have saved in button creation. 

if i use btn[i], its occurs the error.

Comment: Please be little more specific. when the error occurs. and can you please post the error here

Comment: 04-29 00:33:21.690     E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
04-29 00:33:21.690     E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
04-29 00:33:21.700     E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7126)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2173)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1908)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1880)

Comment: No. Now am working on Hash map to store value in button creation. Unable to get value depend upon HashMap KeySet.

Code to put value in HashMap,

     HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String >> hashMap = new       HashMap<Integer ,ArrayList<String>>();

    hashMap.put(btn.getId(),list);

HashMap Retrieve Value,
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    int btnid = v.getId();
for (Integer ihashId :hashMap.keySet()) {
if (btnid == ihashId) {